# How do I use variables from url_for in Flask?

Tags: python, web, flask

So, I'm using Flask to create a sort of to do list thingy, and I'm encoutering a problem.

One of my main pages, when you click the task type you want, does this

```
          <a href={{url_for('add_task_type', task_type=type)}}>{{task_types[type]}}</a>
```

This forwards to,

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_task_type?task_type=1
```

This should send you to the below:

```
@app.route('/add_task_type', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_task_type():
    all_tasks = Task.query.all()
    number = len(all_tasks)
    task_db = Task(id = number, type=task_type, creator = 235026, time=20)
    db.session.add(task_db)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/index')
```

but I'm getting a NameError: global name 'task_type' is not defined.  Why isn't type defined?  Isn't it right there in the URL?  is this the wrong way of passing variables to other pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_task_type?task_type=1
```

The `task_type` is a `GET` parameter and there is in `request`, 
you can access it in your `add_task_type` view with:

```
request.args.get("task_type")
```

so change `add_task_type` view to:

```
from flask import request


def add_task_type():
    ...
    task_type = request.args.get("task_type")
    task_db = Task(id = number, type=task_type, creator = 235026, time=20)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to work.  Is that a sensible way of passing variables from one page to another, btw?  Or am I just being needlessly complicated and missing something obvious.

Comment: @Crimsoneer, I think it's ok to use `GET` variables, one another way that may be useful is using `cookies` or `session`.